# Understanding the "fnull" function and the arguments within "fnull"

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js

## Problem

I'm learning functional programming using the book "Functional Javascript". Currently, I'm fairly puzzled by the console output from the fnull method. I'm looking for an explanation to what is going on and why I am observing the results that I am observing.

I suspect the extra arguments are the iterator and context. However, the function defined by fnull only takes two arguments, total and n. Where does the iterator and context come from?

### Code

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVR75/)

```
function existy(x) { return x != null };

function fnull(fun /*, defaults */) {
    var defaults = _.rest(arguments);

    return function(/* args */) {
        console.log("checking " + arguments[1]);
        var args = _.map(arguments, function(e, i) {
            console.log(e + "," + i);
            return existy(e) ? e : defaults[i];
        });

        return fun.apply(null, args);
    };
};

var safeMult = fnull(function(total, n) { return total * n }, 1, 1);

console.log(_.reduce([1,2,3,null,5], safeMult));
```

### Output

```
checking 2
1,0
2,1
1,2            /* <-- Where do these arguments come from? */
1,2,3,,5,3     /* <-- */
checking 3
2,0
3,1
2,2
1,2,3,,5,3
checking null
6,0
null,1
3,2
1,2,3,,5,3
checking 5
6,0
5,1
4,2
1,2,3,,5,3
30
```

[edits below]

### Reduce Source

Looking over the source code of the reduce method, it brings over the iterator and context. So even though fun uses total and n, iterator and context are being provided.

Below is the source for the reduce method from the underscore.js site:

```
_.reduce = _.foldl = _.inject = function(obj, iterator, memo, context) {
    var initial = arguments.length > 2;
    if (obj == null) obj = [];
    if (nativeReduce && obj.reduce === nativeReduce) {
      if (context) iterator = _.bind(iterator, context);
      return initial ? obj.reduce(iterator, memo) : obj.reduce(iterator);
    }
    each(obj, function(value, index, list) {
      if (!initial) {
        memo = value;
        initial = true;
      } else {
        memo = iterator.call(context, memo, value, index, list);
      }
    });
    if (!initial) throw new TypeError(reduceError);
    return memo;
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the function defined by `fnull` takes any number of arguments. It is the function that is returned by `fnull`.

```
function fnull(...) {
    ...
    return function(/* args */) { // <-- this is the function defined by fnull
        ....
    }
}
```

The function that is passed to `fnull` (`function(total, n) { return total * n }`) is stored in the `fun` argument of `fnull`. In other words:

- `safeMult` is the returned function of `fnull`
- `fun` is `function(total, n) { return total * n }`

What you're writing to the console are the parameters passed to `safeMult` by`_.reduce`.

Comment: So the parameters passed to safeMult by reduce are total, n, iterator, and context? Is that what's going on? If that is the case, should there be a check for iterator and context being null because defaults would only contain [1,1], yet there are four arguments or should [1,1,1,1] be passed into safeMult?

Comment: The parameters passed to safeMult are `memo`, the `value` and `index` of the iteration and the entire `list` (see the docs for [_.reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce)). Those need no null checks because the values are guaranteed to be defined.Except the list is empty or null.